# How to trigger click event using JavaScript on querySelectorAll

Tags: javascript, html

In jQuery i have the following code

```
$("li#credit").trigger('click');
```

This code triggers the click event only on li that has id credit.

Now to do this using JavaScript

```
document.querySelectorAll("li#credit").click();
```

I am getting the error:

> click() is not a function

The page I am working have multiple elements with id "credit", I need to trigger  a click event only on `<li>` that has id credit.

Comment: *"The page I am working have multiple elements with id "credit""*. That's invalid. IDs must be unique. The `querySelectorAll` may fetch them, but it's still messed up.

Comment: Yes, I know that's invalid, but that's the way it is for 10+ years, i don't have any control to change the html, not even to use jQuery

Answer (score 46):

I found this one is clean and simple.

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("ali#credit")).forEach(button=>button.click())
```

from this site: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/loop-queryselectorall-matches/#comment-1602558

**edit 1**
Thanks to Sliavik in comment.

```
document.querySelectorAll("ali#credit").forEach(el=>el.click())
```

is safe to call

Comment: [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach) do exist (Except of IE browser) upon `NodeList` class. You can safely use `document.querySelectorAll("ali#credit").forEach(el=>el.click())`

Comment: This triggers the event only once, what if I want to trigger the event again for the same element?

Comment: querySelectorAll and querying of #id are prohibited to use together, because #id can be only one on the page. Multiple elements with the same ID are prohibited. id="should_be_unique". So you can use only querySelector, but it's not right too (for other reason), right usage is getElementById, and the same ID as already existing anywhere must not be used more than once on page. Use class="instead"

Answer (score 38):

`querySelectorAll` returns a NodeList object ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)) and not a DOM element. A NodeList object contains DOM elements.

Your code needs to change to get the first element and then call `click()`:

```
document.querySelectorAll("li#credit")[0].click();
```

If you want to trigger the `.click()` event to all elements you can do a `for` loop

```
for(var i = 0; i<elems.length; i++) {
    elems[i].click();
}
```

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll("li#credit")[0].click();` is a great & simple option which basically calls the `click()` function on the first and maybe only element in the array.

Comment: Would it be possible to add something like this `addEventListener('click'` if not how would can I call a function if clicked this way `document.querySelectorAll("li#credit")[0].click();`?