# How can I trigger one specific button from querySelecotrAll/forEach?

Tags: javascript, html

**I have some cards like this:**
[image]
And I draw them with this function:

```
let createCard = (header, price, category, size, type, show, img) => {
    let card = document.createElement('div')
    card.className = 'card drk'
    document.querySelector('.container').appendChild(card)

    card.innerHTML = `
        <img src="${img}" alt="">
        <div class="card-description"> 
            <h3>${header}</h3>
            <ul>
                <li>Price: ${price}</li>
                <li>Category: ${category}</li>
                <li>Size: ${size}</li>
                <li>Type: ${type}</li>
                <li>Show: ${show}</li>
            </ul>
            <div class="button-holder">
                <button class="MoreBtn">More</button>
                <i class='bx bx-bookmark-alt'></i>
            </div>
        </div>
    `

    let menuBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.MoreBtn')
    menuBtn.forEach (item => item.addEventListener('click', () => {
        createMoreInfoCard(img, header, category, type, show, price)
    }))

    return card
}
```

And I want to trigger [image: Last lines of above code] <- this function on specific button click. As you can see I tried forEach but on click, it triggers all the buttons. So I want to get one specific button.

Comment: append some id to class so querySelector identify each class as unique so, you can try class like this class="MoreBtn+${id}"

Comment: But after that I need to assign functions separately, don't I? And I have 50 cards like this so it's not handy for me..

Comment: When you're creating  a new card, you're adding a new event listener to All the buttons.

Comment: <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31569890/how-to-trigger-click-event-using-javascript-on-queryselectorall> go this link it will help you

Comment: Oh that's right, thank you. I forgot :D

Answer (score 0):

try this way:

```
let createCard = (header, price, category, size, type, show, img) => {
  let card = document.createElement('div')
  card.className = 'card drk'
  document.querySelector('.container').appendChild(card)

  card.innerHTML = `
            <img src="${img}" alt="">
            <div class="card-description"> 
                <h3>${header}</h3>
                <ul>
                    <li>Price: ${price}</li>
                    <li>Category: ${category}</li>
                    <li>Size: ${size}</li>
                    <li>Type: ${type}</li>
                    <li>Show: ${show}</li>
                </ul>
                <div class="button-holder">
                    <button class="MoreBtn">More</button>
                    <i class='bx bx-bookmark-alt'></i>
                </div>
            </div>
        `
  card.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    if (event.target.classList.contains('.MoreBtn'))
      createMoreInfoCard(img, header, category, type, show, price);
  });

  return card
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to keep track of how many buttons you have or will have in the future, and you just need one event handler bound to an ancestor element, you don't even need `#id`s.

In the example below there's only one clickhandler on a `<section>` -- any clicks within the section will invoke the event handler `more(e)`. Because `more(e)` passes the event object (all event handlers do by default), `e.target` points to the element the user actually clicked. With that knowledge you can design the event handler to delegate the event by determining what reacts and what ignores the click event. In the example, only the elements with `.more` class can react and nothing else.

```js
const sec = document.querySelector('section');
let data = [{
  img: `https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0268/7480/6357/products/cw7356-002_256x.jpg?v=1636057508`,
  name: 'Shoe',
  prc: '$90',
  cat: 'Apparal',
  desc: 'They go on your feet',
  mfg: 'Nike',
  pn: '256D8J'
}, {
  img: `https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0268/7480/6357/products/gm8646_1_400x.jpg?v=1614728158`,
  name: 'Hoodie',
  prc: '$50',
  cat: 'Apparal',
  desc: 'Keeps you warm',
  mfg: 'Adidas',
  pn: '881V9A'
}, {
  img: `https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0268/7480/6357/products/cw7356-002_256x.jpg?v=1636057508`,
  name: 'Shoe',
  prc: '$90',
  cat: 'Apparal',
  desc: 'They go on your feet',
  mfg: 'Nike',
  pn: '256D8J'
}, {
  img: `https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0268/7480/6357/products/gm8646_1_400x.jpg?v=1614728158`,
  name: 'Hoodie',
  prc: '$50',
  cat: 'Apparal',
  desc: 'Keeps you warm',
  mfg: 'Adidas',
  pn: '881V9A'
}];

const createDeck = (node, data) => {
  data.forEach((c, i) => {
    let card = `
<article class="card" data-idx='${i}'>
<img src="${c.img}">
<fieldset><legend><h3>${c.name} <br>${c.prc}</h3></legend><ul class='list'><li>Category: ${c.cat}</li>
<li>Size: ${c.desc}</li>        <li>Manufacturer: ${c.mfg}</li>      <li>Part No.: ${c.pn}</li>          </ul><button class="more">More</button></fieldset></article>`;
    node.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', card);
  });
};
const more = e => {
  const btn = e.target;
  if (btn.matches('.more')) {
    let list = btn.previousElementSibling;
    list.classList.toggle('open');
  }
};

createDeck(sec, data);

sec.onclick = more;
```

```css
:root {
  font: 1ch/1.5 'Segoe UI'
}

body {
  font: 2ch
}

main {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 10px auto;
}

section {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: max-content;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

.card {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 30vw;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden
}

img {
  display: block;
  width: 30vw;
}

fieldset {}

legend {}

.list {
  display: none;
  font-size: 1rem;
  margin-left: -30px
}

.more {
  display: block;
  margin-left: 10vw;
  font: inherit;
}

.open {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<main>
  <section></section>
</main>
```