# How to check for multiple ID attributes if they are being clicked with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, event-handling, jquery-selectors, addeventlistener

I am trying to check for activity on any of some specific ID attributes on my webpage with JavaScript, and if they are activated, I want to execute some code. The code is working for a single attribute with `document.querySelector` but not for `document.querySelectorAll`.

I have tried the solutions posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31569890/how-to-trigger-click-event-using-javascript-on-queryselectorall) but without success, as I run into the following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment
```

My code is simple:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
    Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("#id_types, #id_cons_1")).forEach(button=>button.click()) = function() { 
        document.querySelector("#id_new_name").value= some_value_to_be_assigned
    }})
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "What am I doing wrong?" ~ using a `python` tag for your `javascript` question, comes to mind.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for the `DOMContentLoaded` event handler, just put a `script` with the following at the end of the `body` (just before the closing `body` tag).

There is also no need for `Array.from` since `forEach` is supported on the node list returned from `querySelectorAll()`.

Then, you need to set up a `click` event for each button as shown below (`button.click() = function....`, doesn't set up an event handler, it invokes a click event).

```js
document.querySelectorAll("#id_types, #id_cons_1").forEach(function(button) { 
  button.addEventListener("click", function(event){
    document.querySelector("#id_new_name").textContent = "some_value_to_be_assigned";
  });
});
```

```html
<button type="button" id="id_types">button</button>
<button type="button" id="id_cons_1">button</button>
<div id="id_new_name">some value</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your assistance. I get prompted: ```(parameter) event: Event
'event' is declared but its value is never read.ts(6133)``` with your code. In addition I cannot use for example type="button". ID attributes of interest do not have common classes or types and are generated automatically in Django by ModelForms

Comment: @Rivered Your question is not tagged and doesn't mention anything about Django. As you can see, the code works just fine here and is correct. You must have other problems.